# Not able to access request object of UIWebView inside webViewDidStartLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I am trying to access request object of UIWebView in webViewDidStartLoad in the following manner:

```
- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"req : %@", [webView request]);
    -----
    -----
}
```

It displays following in console :
 **req : (null)**

Is the above possible or I am doing something wrong?
down vote

I donot want to use it inside `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:)request navigationType:` as this method does not get called always for `goBack` and `goForward` methods

Comment: How do you set up your webView & request?

Comment: I have added the WebView from IB and set its delegate to one of my controller class in which I have implemented UIWebView delegate methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will still have to consider `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

Did some testing and it looks like the `[webView request]` is 'one step behind' in delegate methods.

This was the code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"req1a : %@", [request URL]);    
    NSLog(@"req1b : %@", [[webView request] URL]);    

    return YES;
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"req2 : %@", [[webView request] URL]);    
}
```

And this were the results for initial (*about:blank*) and after click (*some video stream, not actual printout*) request:

**initial request:**

req1a : about:blank

req1b : (null)

req2 :

**after click to a link:**

req1a : xttp://origin.biokoda.tv/...

req1b : about:blank

req2 : about:blank

It looks like `[webview request]` is holding last loaded request.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also researched and found that either we have to use shouldStartLoadWithRequest method or webViewDidFinishLoad method. Don't know the reason that why it is not allowed to access in webViewDidStartLoad. Thanks. Marking you correct.